# Password Protect a url in Nginx

Tags: nginx, password-protection

My question is similar to [Password protect a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14603568/1331135) except I'm trying to achieve this in Nginx instead of Apache.

Please suggest way to do it. It's a url with dynamic content, not a file.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html

Comment: That does help Thank you @alexeyten How to do this for single url? Not the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Look at [module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html) to find out passwd file format. Basically Apache's one will be good.

```
location /protected/path {
    auth_basic           "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
}
```