# Laravel 4 separate admin driectory htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, admin, backend, .htpasswd

I use Laravel 4, and I like to separate the admin area, to a different folder.
I wnat this separation by phosocally, not only by filters, and route tricks. But I don't want to deal with two different laravel installation.

I already use different views, contorrels, and modells for the admin area, but I lik to use htpasswd protected folder as well, witch protects the admin page.

Can someone suggest me a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. All requests to your app goes through the public directory only. if you somehow make changes to the .htaccess and allow access with password to appurl/admin the request still goes thorough the index.php where you need to implement UAC on the php controller. so intern .htaccess password won't make sense.

Comment: That's correct, for me, I want double authentication. Becouse I think it's more secure if two different provider used for the aut, one is the apache method, and than the laravel method.

Comment: Have your tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url