# How Require expr directive works in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to **password protect** for `URL` `/user/login` and `/user/login/`.

I added below code at my `.htaccess` file. But it prompted on all `pages` including `home page`.

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/project/.htpasswd
AuthName "Private access"
AuthType Basic
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^.*/user/login/$#
require user dummyuser
```

I know **problem** lies within `Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^.*/user/login/$#`.How can I correct this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url see this.

Comment: Ok...I got that working. BTW can u get me reference for how `Require expr %{REQUEST_URI}` works other than official doc?