# How can allow a url type from .htaccess password protection?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site which have .htaccess password protected. Now I want to allow for some URL of the site.

https://www.exampale.com is password protected.
But I don't want any password popup show for https://www.exampale.com/test/page/{variable}

Can this possible in .htaccess file ?

Need reverse of [Password protect a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it in conjunction with `mod_setenv` directive as:

```
# set variable NO_PASS if URI starts with /test/page/
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/test/page/" NO_PASS

# Allow NO_PASS but ask for password otherwise
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /Full/Path/To/passwords
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=NO_PASS
```