# How to tell Jekyll to hide one page from search engines?

Tags: jekyll, noindex

I have a website consisting of my public profile, made in Jekyll.

It also contains one page, say 'details.html', which contains more personal information about me. I want only those people to see this page whom I give out the link to. In particular, I'd like to hide it from search engines.

How do I best do this? I've heard I can add a robots.txt file or include a meta tag 'nofollow' or 'noindex'.

1. Which is the usual solution here?
2. If the way to go is to add a meta tag, how do I add it in only one page given a standard Jekyll setup?

Comment: "how to tell Jekyll to hide"...am I the only one who finds that unintentionally amusing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `robots.txt` is the standard way of telling search engines what to index and what not to (not just for Jekyll, but for websites in general).

Just create a file called `robots.txt` in the root of your Jekyll site, with the paths that should not be indexed.

e.g.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /2017/02/11/post-that-should-not-be-indexed/
Disallow: /page-that-should-not-be-indexed/
Allow: /
```

Jekyll will *automagically* copy the `robots.txt` to the folder where the site gets generated.

---

You can also test your `robots.txt` to make sure it is working the way you expect: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en

---

#### Update 2021-08-02 - Google Specific settings:

You can prevent a page from appearing in Google Search by including a `noindex` meta tag in the page's HTML code, or by returning a `noindex` header in the HTTP response

There are two ways to implement `noindex`: as a meta tag and as an HTTP response header. They have the same effect; choose the method that is more convenient for your site.

##### `<meta>` tag

To prevent most search engine web crawlers from indexing a page on your site, place the following meta tag into the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

To prevent only Google web crawlers from indexing a page:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

##### HTTP response header

Instead of a meta tag, you can also return an `X-Robots-Tag` header with a value of either `noindex` or `none` in your response. Here's an example of an HTTP response with an `X-Robots-Tag` instructing crawlers not to index a page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
(...)
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
(...)
```

More details: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/block-indexing

Comment: But then a normal user could go to www.mysite.com/robots.txt and find these URLs, right?

Comment: Okay. That's suboptimal, but not fatal. Do you know if the meta tag solution works too? What would be the standard application for that tag then?

Comment: The meta tag solution would also work with most search engines (including Google - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en), but you need to do one or the other, not both.

Comment: From [Google's own documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro): "A robots.txt file tells search engine crawlers which URLs the crawler can access on your site. This is used mainly to avoid overloading your site with requests; it is not a mechanism for keeping a web page out of Google. To keep a web page out of Google, [block indexing with `noindex`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/block-indexing) or password-protect the page."

Comment: For clarity it is important to highlight that `Allow: /` does not exist as standard directive. Further reading: http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
---
layout: 
sitemap: false
---
```

So, whenever you include `sitemap: false` line in your front matter, you can exclude that page from your sitemap.

---

check:

- add `gem 'jekyll-sitemap'` to your site’s `Gemfile` and run `bundle`
- add the following to your site’s _config.yml:

```yaml
plugins:
    - jekyll-sitemap
```

Answer (score 0):

A robots.txt file is a great solution, but [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url) might be better for this purpose. Also, make sure you have a private repository!

Note that hosting your code on [CloudCannon](https://cloudcannon.com/) (paid account) allows you to set up all these things easily from within their interface.