# Adding htpasswd to a certain URL (not the whole website)

Tags: apache, apache2.4, .htpasswd

I am trying to place a password on www.example.com/need-password/ url only.  ie: www.example.com should just work as normal without needing a password.  I am also looking to do this *ONLY* using Apache 2.4 (not Apache2.2)

Comment: Have you tried this solution: [Password protect a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url#answer-26980313). It's said to be working on Apache v2.4.25.

Comment: Yes.  I even commented that it didn't work before posting this question as seen here: https://i.imgur.com/uUjM5mw.png

Comment: Ohh, sorry. Didn't check the username....

Comment: Have you enabled the authgroupfile Apache module? If not, maybe you need to run `sudo a2enmod authz_groupfile` to enable it. I haven't tried this, so it's just a guess.

Comment: Yes I have.  It is done.