# Htpasswd specific url in laravel htaccess

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have a Laravel application where I want to restrict the access to a specific URL (specifically the url of the api documentation) /api/documentation. I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url) and I tried it but I keep getting Internal Server Error, I don't know how to put the code.

This is my `.htaccess` right here. So far the default laravel .htaccesss:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where or how do I have to put the code on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603568/password-protect-a-specific-url)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a different form of authentication. But if you're set on using HTTP auth, at least make sure you use bcrypt or something secure when generating your htpasswd file.

But to answer your question...

Your `.htaccess` file should have something like:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Super Secret"
AuthUserFile /some/location/where/your/.htpasswd/file/is
Require valid-user
```

Comment: But that will lock every single url in my site, right? I just want to restrict a specific URL that is **/api/documentation**

Comment: https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/laravel-middleware-basic-auth-implementation-88b777361b5c